# Problems applying kubernetes ingress tls

Tags: spring, docker, kubernetes

Hello My project has a total of 2 services.
It consists of a service composed of Spring MVC and a service composed of nodejs, and both services are using http. 
I use Ingress as one domain. and I applied tls to this ingress and modified it to use https.

However,  I am getting a 502 error. I think this is because Spring MVC and nodejs server use http.
Can't I solve it without applying https to two servers?

My Ingress is

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: service-loadbalancing
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: domain-address
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: spring-service
            servicePort: 9000
        - path: /index
          backend:
            serviceName: node-service
            servicePort: 9001
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - domain-address
    secretName: nginx-tls
```

THANK!!!

My ingress pod logs

```
172.17.0.1 - - [01/Apr/2020:02:10:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 4236 "https://mydomain/login?timeout=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36" 18 0.007 [default-spring-service-9000] [] 172.17.0.8:1111 
2020/04/01 02:10:28 [error] 6773#6773: *7390742 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /resources/aiaas/kr/css/reset.css HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://172.17.0.9:1111/resources/aiaas/kr/css/reset.css", host: "mydomain:8891", referrer: "https://mydomain:8891/"
```

Comment: How did you install the nginx ingress controller?

Comment: I installed it like this:

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.27.1/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.27.1/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/service-nodeport.yaml

thank

Comment: it worked before applying tls ?

Comment: It worked fine before applying tls.
Additionally, there is no HTTPS in Spring Tomcat and nodejs

Comment: can you add logs from ingress controller pods?

Comment: Your cluster is On-Prem or local? How did you get this 502? Via browser or curl?

Comment: @ Arghya Sadhu
I posted a log to the question

Comment: @PjoterS
I am using minikube and I am getting an error in the browser

Comment: The current service namespace and the ingress namespace are different
503 error when using the same namespace

Comment: I mean if you are using your local env or you are using any cloud provider? Minikube can be run on both envs.